# Does Spring @RestController enable CORS by default?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm reading through this [Spring security tutorial](https://github.com/oleersoy/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/blob/master/basic/README.adoc) and it mentions that we might see 2 requests for the dynamic resource because there is a CORS negotiation for this controller:

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    @RestController
    public class UiApplication {

      @RequestMapping("/resource")
      public Map<String,Object> home() {
        Map<String,Object> model = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        model.put("id", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        model.put("content", "Hello World");
        return model;
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UiApplication.class, args);
      }

    }
```

Just curious as to whether the `@RestController` annotation enables CORS by default?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No**.

You need to add **@CrossOrigin** annotation by **yourself** to get CORS Support in Spring.

**Why:**

Enabling CORS (*Cross-origin resource sharing*) **by default** will be a **serious security issue**.

Consider this example from [official](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cors.html) docs.

> For security reasons, browsers prohibit AJAX calls to resources
>   residing outside the current origin. For example, as you’re checking
>   your **bank account in one tab**, you could have the **evil.com** website open
>   in another tab. The scripts from evil.com should **not** be able to make
>   AJAX requests to your bank API (e.g., **withdrawing money** from your
>   account!) using your credentials.

Comment: So just curious ... can there be a CORS negotiation for the controller if the controller is not CORS enabled?

Answer (score 3):

No, see https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/:

> So that the RESTful web service will include CORS access control
>   headers in its response, you just have to add a @CrossOrigin
>   annotation to the handler method:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:9000")
@GetMapping("/greeting")
public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(required=false, defaultValue="World") String name) {
   System.out.println("==== in greeting ====");
   return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(), String.format(template, name));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

CORS support is disabled by default and is only enabled once the `endpoints.cors.allowedorigins`
property has been set. The configuration below permits GET and POST calls from the
example.com domain:

```
endpoints.cors.allowed-origins=http://example.com
endpoints.cors.allowed-methods=GET,POST
```

[Spring boot ref guide.](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-cors)

Check [EndpointCorsProperties](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/EndpointCorsProperties.java) for a complete list of options.

Comment: For those looking in the future - this is only for Spring Actuator - not your controllers

Answer (score 1):

No. The scripts from evil.com should not be able to make AJAX requests to your bank, for example